# Endpoint \"GET /socket.io/\" not found."

Tags: typescript, socket.io, loopback4

https://github.com/alexkander/loopback4-example-websocket-app

when i changed `package.json` dependency to new version
it doesn't see the path url and throws the following error
Endpoint `\"GET /socket.io/\"` not found.
works fine on old dependency
How can I fix this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IKKA.png

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve] in the question itself. "I changed this third party code in a way I have described only in the vaguest of possible terms and now I get this error message" does not make it easy to help you.

Comment: "when i changed package.json dependency to new version" — This is still **very** vague. What dependency? What new version? You still lack a [mcve].